# How can we emulate mobile device as a card after reading data from card with NFC?

Tags: flutter, dart, nfc, rfid, hce

I am building an app that can do payments from mobile devices to RFID devices. I  am able to scan the card and get the detail but I am not able to simulate the mobile device as a card. Is there any possible solution?

I have tried nfc_manager packages to read the card details and then I tried nfc_emulator to emulate the device as HCE(Hosted card emulation).

Comment: You tried HCE which is the only solution for Android (there is no solution for iOS), may be show your code and more details so that people might be able to help.

Comment: How did you read card details, can you please share the code.